# Issues with Merge. Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Tags: r, merge, type-conversion

Folks,

I am facing an issue while merging two dataframes. I have two datframes. I have included limited data in terms of rows/cols (original data is pretty big) for each dataframe as shown below:

```
 DF1
 Cost.Centre.Code       GBP
       322018    0.00000
       400629    0.00000
       400629  163.60005
       400629    0.00000
       400629   28.00001
       400629   0.00000

 DF2
       Cost.Centre.Code                  Function
       400629            Global Functions
       570001            Business Manages Services
       570002            Business Manages Services
       570003            Global Functions
       570004            Business Manages Services
       570005            OTHER
```

I am trying to get values from DF2 in DF1. I have done type conversion (both class and mode) for Cost.Centre.Code in DF2 to match it to what is there in DF1.

```
DF2$Cost.Centre.Code <- as.numeric(as.character(DF2$Cost.Centre.Code))
DF2 <- data.frame(lapply(DF2, factor))
```

Now Cost.Centre.Code in both the dataframes is numeric and stored as factors.

Now I am trying to merge them using the below mentioned command:

```
DF3 <- merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by.x =  'Cost.Center.Code', by.y = 'Cost.Center.Code', all.x = TRUE)
```

I am getting an error "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column".

I have already gone through similar posts on SF about similar error, but their issues were slightly different than mine. Any troubleshooting is not helping me.

I am not sure if there is some issue with type conversion. I am relatively new to R programming and any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `Cost.Centre.Code` in both your df's and `Cost.Center.Code` in both your `by` arguments. (`tre` versus `ter`.)

Comment: you have a typo center / centre

Comment: Thank you @Moody_Mudskipper. Foolish of me to miss that :)...It is working now.